# How to add a loop for a replay button in a music player in scratch

Tags: loops, mit-scratch, replay

I made a music player in scratch, that fast forwards and rewinds 4 songs in a playlist. I tried creating a replay button that replays the same song over and over when it’s pressed till it’s pressed again, but I’m stuck.

I tried using creating two different sprites , one for replaying the song and one for ending the song.

Comment: "I'm stuck" is not a question; it's too vague for Stack Overflow. Please edit and improve your question; see [ask] for tips. If you need more personal guidance in writing code, please ask your question at [Scratch's "help with scripts" forum](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/7/).

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this code to replay a sound on a key/button event:

[image]